# how to save images captured by my industrial camera fast into SSD

Tags: image, camera, computer-vision, storage, solid-state-drive

I have a industrial camera which takes 120 frames per second. It connects with my PC through a USB 3.0 cable and the frames are stably transferred into my PC at a frame rate of 120fps if I just show them. However, when I try to save the frames into my SSD (M.2 PCIE interface) in jpeg format, I can only save 30 frames per second. Each jpeg file is about 80KB and it will be about 10MBps if I save all 120 frames per second. I have tested my SSD and it has at least 100MBps for writing data. So where can it go wrong?

Btw, the API provided by the camera is Windows C++ API and I am using Visual studio for the capturing and writing program. One way I can think of is to save the images in the memory for a certain time and then I stop capturing and dump the images out to the disk. My application needs to keep the camera capturing all the time. So I am thinking if there is a way to save those images continuously in the SSD. My PC has i7 and 32GB memory.

Comment: Are you running Windows or Linux? How many seconds do you need to capture for? What programming language and tools are you using?

Comment: If reading(via usb) and writing(to SSD) is serial then bottle neck is your writing. So put reading in one thread and write in the main thread. This might improve the FPS

Comment: If you have a multi-core CPU, you might consider having 1 thread capturing frames and maybe 4 threads processing frames. You would create the 4 processing threads at startup and then notify them in turn as a frame arrives, i.e. frame 1 to thread 1, frame 2 to thread 2, frame 3 to thread 3, frame 4 to thread 4, frame 5 to thread 1... The threads would then have four times as long to convert to JPEG and write before they were called upon to process another frame.

Comment: thanks for all your valuable comments. I think multi-threading would be a good direction. I will try that and let you guys know.

Answer (score 1):

The bottleneck is not I/O but the processing of converting raw to jpeg which is done by SDK on PC. Try to save raw in real-time and convert it to jpeg offline.